# When using persistence in Redis, do key expiration respect original time?

Tags: redis

Let's say I'm using a single Redis with AOF persistence every second. All keys expire after one second (using EXPIRE). Then momentary power outage restarts the machine and it takes Redis 1.2 seconds to be available again.

Could any key still be alive? Or when the AOF log is restored, the last added keys expire automatically since it has passed more than a second from the original moment in which they were added?

Does RDB behaves like AOF in this case?

Comment: I assume you're not worried about edge scenarios like "when the server rebooted, it did a time sync, which changed the system clock by 1.5 seconds in the other direction, so for .3 of a second the keys were value *anyway*"?

Comment: I did not think about that TBH, good point. I guess that the possibility of stale cache is always there somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expiry is respected in both persistence modes, AOF and RDB alike.

Comment: Meaning that there won't be any key there, right? Is there any documentation about this fact? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure there is formal documentation about this, would "it just works" suffice? ;) Seriously though, documentation aside, I'm somewhat familiar with the internals and afaik expiry is honored post recovery from persistence (excluding yet-to-be-discovered software defects ofc).

Comment: I was just curious :) Cheers.

Comment: Always stay curious friend :)